# How do I query data created from last week's Sunday to Saturday so that this data can be included in a batch process to be run on Tuesday?

Tags: soql, conga

I want to run a batch on Tuesday to process records created from Last week's Sunday to Saturday. I want these records to be processed as part of document generation using Conga. I cannot use LAST_N_DAYS:n as users should be able to manually hit the button on any day of the week and still the button should query only records last week's Sunday to Saturday. How can I create this query?

Comment: Are you talking about Batch Apex, or a Conga-specific batch process?

Comment: Conga Batch - its a new add on from Conga that helps schedule batch document generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date literal `LAST_WEEK` in a SOQL query to get records from the last week. See the [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) doc. One caveat is that "Your locale determines the first day of the week" so that may not be always Sun to Sat depending on your setup.

Example:

```
select Id from Object where CreatedDate = LAST_WEEK
```

Comment: Conga batch will be scheduled so the query will run in system mode right, so will it take into consideration the default locale?